# get facebook post id from url link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to get a post id from an url in the graph explorer 
for example I try to get the ID of this post in graph explorer 
this is the url

http://www.imdb.com/gallery/rg1859820288/mediaviewer/rm1167930112

And on Facebook this is the post 
https://www.facebook.com/imdb/posts/10155250004608949

So the ID of the post is 10155250004608949

When I try to put my link on the graph explorer

It return me

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "1460657060613493",
      "description": "Untitled Jurassic World Sequel (2018)",
      "title": "Latest Stills",
      "type": "article",
      "updated_time": "2017-03-08T22:45:48+0000"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 16
   },
   "id": "http://www.imdb.com/gallery/rg1859820288/mediaviewer/rm1167930112"
}
```

I don't know what it is this id : 1460657060613493

So I don't know if it is possible to get the post id like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what it is this id : 1460657060613493

That is the id of the Open Graph object that the URL `http://www.imdb.com/gallery/rg1859820288/mediaviewer/rm1167930112` represents.

> So I don't know if it is possible to get the post id like that

Of course it is not possible to get the post id via the IMDB URL, because “the” post id does simply not exist - multiple users and pages could have shared that IMDB URL.